# How can I set a property depending on properties of the same model on collection creation ? Nodejs - Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my api, I'm having a modal with a schema basically like the following :

```
let CaseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    caseNumber: String,
    caseType: { type: String, required: true },
    caseSubType: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CaseSubType' },
...
```

and in the route, when adding a new case (.post) I wanted to :

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const oneCase = new Case({
            caseNumber: caseNumber(req.body),
            caseType: req.body.caseType,
            caseSubType: req.body.caseSubType,
...
)}
const savedCase = await oneCase.save()
        res.json(savedCase);
```

where caseNumber(case) is a function that i have defined upwards, it uses 'caseType' and 'caseSubType' defined in the same collection; example :

```
caseNumber = (case) => {
      return (case.caseType + " - " + case.caseSubType)
}
```

And unfortunately, that didn't work in any way. So, is there a way ?

Comment: What didn't work specifically? Could you be more specific about details?

Comment: @AnkushVerma that line " caseNumber: caseNumber(req.body), " where I call the function
it's always empty, like it's doing nothing !

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the parameter `case` to any other name, because `case` is a reserved word, for more details refer [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp),

- changed from `case` to `cases`, you can set any name as you want except listed in reference links

```
caseNumber = (cases) => {
  return (cases.caseType + " - " + cases.caseSubType)
}
```